# The primary menu works fine on my laptop, but not on phone

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, nav

I'm using WordPress to build up a website. Yesterday afternoon everything was fine, then the header nav just crashed out of blue. It first started with showing unattributed focus properties but fixed that issue with a:focus. It works fine on the laptop, but not on mobile devices. It doesn't have active colours on small screens, but I wish it has. Thanks for helping out!

```
.site-header .tab a:focus{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
    outline:none !important;
}

.site-header .tab a:active{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
}

.site-header .tab a:hover{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
}

.site-header .tab a:visited{ 
    color: #fff !important;
}

.site-header .tab a:after{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
.site-header .tab a:link{ 
    color: #fff !important;
}

.site-header .tab a:active{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The colour you want for the :active pseudo-class is being over-written by

```
@media screen and (max-width: 800px)
.site-header .tab a:link {
    color: #fff;
}
.site-header .tab a:link {
    color: #fff!important;
}
```

It seems you are using JS to add a focus class to each element. You could use this same JS to add in style css to your elements. This will overwrite anything written elsewhere. It also seems that you need to remove .focus from all other nav li a upon clicking the most recent nav li a.

If you'd rather not JS, then to avoid overwriting CSS, maybe consider the hierarchy and specificity of your code. I would the following code lower down in your custom CSS file with a greater specificity. Maybe like so:

```
.site-header .primary-menu .tab a:active{ 
    color: #FF6508 !important;
}
```

Comment: ccartstudio.co.nz.   Cheers!!

Comment: .primary-menu seems not to work here, tho it should be that way normally. Maybe the key is to find the right class. May I ask where I can find the menu's class. Cheers.